# How to check with query if a form has been submitted on onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to detect if the user has leaved the page or if he submit the form, i tried something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
if ($('form').submit() == true) {
    console.log('form submitted!');
} else{
    console.log('good bye!');
};
};
```

I need this because if he leave the current page i will run a php code to delete some information but if he submit the form the php will store the information in another place.

Thanks!

Comment: If the user has left the page, you can't run any more JavaScript on that page anyway. (And even so, you can't use JS to trigger PHP code in the same page.) What I think you need to do is modify whatever PHP page is receiving your submitted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't think you can do it like this. You may want to use a classname or some other attribute in the form to mark the submission, either by js if you're submitting with ajax or in php, checking the post / get data.

For example:

```
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
     //post ajax
     ,success: function(data){ 
     //do other stuff
     $('$myform').addClass('submited');
     }
  });
```

Then,

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 if ($('#myform').hasClass('submited') {
   //do submitted stuff
 } else{
  // dont 
 };
 };
```

In case of normal submission, the conditional would have to do with $_POST or $_GET data and the way you build the html in your php file, with the same logic.

Comment: Works perfect for me, thank you very much!!! when i get a least 15 points of reputation i will vote up your answer.